# Is there a way in UI5 to validate JSON data against a JSON schema without using third party tools?

Tags: sapui5

Like the title describes, I want to validate json data received from an api against a json schema, but didn't found anything in the official documentation or in the internet. Are there any solutions in UI5 without using third party tools like [json-schema](http://json-schema.org) or [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) ?

I tried to create custom data type with sap/ui/base/DataType .createType, but to validate complex json data with deep nested properties is quite complicated. The same with extending from sap/ui/model/SimpleType...

Does UI5 provide any solution to validate properties of controls and components against complex json schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not

Basically if don't find anything like that in the Developer Guide, you need a third party lib.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is an official project from SAP at GitHub: [@ui5/manifest](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-manifest). It's also published via [JSON Schema Store](https://www.schemastore.org/json/).